# Ruby on Rails - pundit gem - undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Don't know why this is happening here.

NoMethodError in PostsController#update
undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass

My user has admin : true and I can't update other users.posts.

I want to let all users see the content, but only registered users can create content. And if the user is admin or the creator of that content he can edit/update/destroy it as well.

post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
  validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 240 }


end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include Encryptable

  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  has_attached_file :avatar
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
  validates :level, numericality: { less_than_or_equal_to: 100,  only_integer: true }, allow_blank: true

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable

  before_validation :downcase_email #, :populate_iv_fields #if you need/want iv to change more often
  before_create :create_encryption_key
  after_create :save_encryption_key
  after_create :build_user_consents
  attr_encrypted :email, key: :encryption_key
  has_many :user_consents, dependent: :destroy

  #entry point for exporting user's personal information
  def self.export_personal_information(user_id)
    return nil unless User.exists?(user_id)
    descendants = ApplicationRecord.descendants.reject{|model| !model.has_personal_information?}
    result = Hash.new
    descendants.each do |descendant|
      result[descendant.name] = descendant.export_personal_information_from_model(user_id)
    end
    return result
  end
  #simplest example, we just export to json
  def self.export_personal_information_from_model(user_id)
    return User.find(user_id).to_json
  end
  #overwrite this to true for methods that you will want to be included in export_personal_information
  def self.has_personal_information?
    true
  end

  #helper method if you are creating a user from console and want them to have all consents set
  def fill_consents
    hash = Hash.new
    ConsentCategory.all.map(&:id).each do |id|
      hash[id]='on'
    end
    self.registration_consents=hash
  end

  #unfortunately not having an email field that you can just "write to" breaks
  #Devise. Below some necessary workarounds

  def email_changed?
    encrypted_email_changed?
  end

  def downcase_email
    self.email = self.email.downcase
  end

  def registration_consents=(consents)
    @consents = consents
  end

  def registration_consents
    @consents
  end

  validate                  :validate_consents_completeness
  validates_presence_of     :email, if: :email_required?
  validates_uniqueness_of   :username, allow_blank: false, if: :username_changed?
  validates_length_of       :username, within: 6..20, allow_blank: true

  validate                  :validate_email_uniqueness #validates_uniqueness_of :email, allow_blank: true, if: :email_changed?
  validates_format_of       :email, with: Devise.email_regexp, allow_blank: true, if: :email_changed?
  validates_presence_of     :password, if: :password_required?
  validates_confirmation_of :password, if: :password_required?
  validates_length_of       :password, within: Devise.password_length, allow_blank: true

  def password_required?
    !persisted? || !password.nil? || !password_confirmation.nil?
  end
  #end original devise

  def email_changed?
    self.encrypted_email_changed?
  end

  def email_required?
    true
  end

  def email_unique?
    records = Array(self.class.find_by_email(self.email))
    records.reject{|u| self.persisted? && u.id == self.id}.empty?
  end
  #unfortunately, this is an O(n) operation now that has to go through ALL the users to see if an email is unique. Sorry!
  #if you need it to ne O(1) then consider adding email_hash field instead
  def self.find_by_email(email)
    users = User.all
    users.each do |user|
      return user if user.email.downcase == email.downcase
    end
    return nil
  end

  protected

  def validate_email_uniqueness
    errors.add(:email, :taken) unless email_unique?
  end

  def validate_consents_completeness
    return if self.id #we assume that already created user has all consents
    errors.add(:registration_consents, 'Sie müssen allen erforderlichen Bedingungen zustimmen um fortzufahren.') and return unless self.registration_consents
    consents = ConsentCategory.where(mandatory: true).map(&:id)
    ids = self.registration_consents.keys.map(&:to_i) #we are relying on a fact that checkboxes that are not checked are not sent to Rails back-end at all
    consents.each do |consent_type|
      errors.add(:registration_consents, 'Sie müssen allen erforderlichen Bedingungen zustimmen um fortzufahren.') and return unless ids.include?(consent_type)
    end
  end

  def build_user_consents
    ids = registration_consents.keys
    categories = ConsentCategory.where(id: ids)
    raise 'Die vom Benutzer eingereichte Zustimmungsliste enthält Objekte, die nicht in der Datenbank vorhanden sind!' if categories.count != ids.count
    categories.each do |category|
      consent = UserConsent.new
      consent.consent_category = category
      consent.user = self
      consent.requires_revalidation = false
      consent.agreed_at = self.created_at
      consent.save!
    end
  end

end
```

post_policy.rb

```
       class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :post

  def initialize(user, post)
    @user = user
    @post = post
  end

  def index?
    true
  end

  def create?
    user.present?
  end

  def new?
    user.present?
  end

  def update?
    return true if post.user_id == user.id || user == user.admin?
  end

  def destroy?
    return true if post.user_id == user.id || user == user.admin?
  end

  private

  def post
    record
  end
end
```

application_policy.rb

```
    class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    @user = user
    @record = record
  end

  def index?
    false
  end

  def show?
    false
  end

  def create?
    false
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    user.admin?
  end

  def edit?
    user.admin?
  end

  def destroy?
    user.admin?
  end

  class Scope
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      scope.all
    end
  end
end
```

post_controller

```
    class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_post, only: %i[destroy edit update comment_owner upvote downvote]
  after_action :verify_authorized, except: [:index, :show]

  layout '_app_nav'

  def index
    return redirect_to post_path(params[:post_id]) if params[:post_id]
    return redirect_to user_path(params[:user_id]) if params[:user_id]
    @post = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
    @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
    @user = User.all
    @posts = if params[:suche]

             else
               Post.all.order('created_at DESC')

             end
    @comments = Comment.all

  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new

  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    authorize @post
    if @post.save!
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @user = @post.user
    @comments = Comment.where(post_id: @post).order('created_at DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
  end

  def edit
    authorize @post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    authorize @post
    @post.update(title: params[:title], body: params[:post_params])
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy
    authorize @post

    redirect_to posts_path
  end

=begin
  def upvote
    @post.upvote_from current_user
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  def downvote
    @post.downvote_from current_user
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
=end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :user_id)
  end

  def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end


end
```

application_controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |user_params|
      user_params.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, registration_consents: {})
    end
  end

  private

  def user_not_authorized
    flash[:alert] = 'test'
    redirect_to(root_path)
  end

end
```

registrations_controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController


  private

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :username, :avatar, :current_password, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

edit:

updating my post_policy.rb with @post such as `return true if user.present? && user == @post.user || user == user.admin?` resolves in -> Pundit::NotAuthorizedError in PostsController#update
not allowed to update?

Comment: Can you post your `PostsController` code? It would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using devise you can use this callback, in your application_controller.rb to validate you have a user logged in.

> before_action :authenticate_user!

With that you avoid doing

> user.present?

Your post_policy.rb should look like this

```
  class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :post

  def initialize(user, post)
    @user = user
    @post = post
  end

  def index?
    true
  end

  def create?
    user.present?
  end

  def new?
    user.present?
  end

  def update?
    return true if record.user_id == user.id || user == user.admin?
  end

  def destroy?
    return true if record.user_id == user.id || user == user.admin?
  end

  private

  def post
    record
  end
end
```

Also, to avoid that users can enter the links in the browser, you can do an extra step on you controller, which is adding the following callback and method

```
class PostsController < ApplicationControl
    before_action :authorization

    private

    def authorization
      authorize(Post)
    end
end
```

EDIT:

Make sure your ApplicationController looks like this one to prevent the error Pundit::NotAuthorizedError.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

  private

  def user_not_authorized
    flash[:alert] = 'You are not authorized to perform this action.'
    redirect_to(root_path)
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, I am using devise. Tried that just now and got  NoMethodError in PostsController#update
undefined method `user_id' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Are you using the devise callback?  before_action :authenticate_user!

Comment: Yes, I am using the callback. Added the update to it, but I still recieve the nomethoderror

Comment: Are your posts saving the user.id? Can you check that? Go to the console and write Post.last if your user_id is nil, let me know

Comment: I just saw your controller, you should move the callback authenticate_user! to user model and not having it in posts controller. Also you're not setting the update method in that before_action since you're allowing all your methods there, change the first PostController line to this one:  before_action :authenticate_user!

Comment: Yes, my posts save the user_id. By moving this to user model, you mean users_controller? yes i added that already

Comment: Leave it in Posts controller but only write before_action :authenticate_user! since you're allowing all your methods there

Comment: Okay, did that. but I still have undefined_method user_id

Comment: Delete that before_action from post_controller move it to application_controller   before_action :authenticate_user! it's better to have it there. Then restart your server, logout and login back.

Comment: I have everything changed the way you mentioned it and still recieve NoMethodError in PostsController#update
undefined method `user_id' for nil:NilClass - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: My last suggestion would be that you change in your create method in posts_controller, this line  "@post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)"
 to this one "@post = Post.new(post_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))" Then create a new post and try to do whatever you do there. Also delete the     authorize @post that you have on your post_controller methods if you're using the before_action authorize I suggested

Comment: Since the post has a user_id I don't think that's the problem at all. Somehow if I type in record it outputs as nil. I think that is the problem

Comment: then change record to post since you have the attr_accessors there

Comment: I updated my question with more necessary code I think. still not working.

Comment: what about your models? user and post?

Comment: take a look at how I implement Pundit in this project https://github.com/xvega/overtime-app

Answer (score 0):

In your `PostsController`, you need to include `update` method inside array where you specify before which methods should `authenticate_user` before action run:

```
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:create, :destroy, :new, :edit, :update]
```